# jQuery calculate hours function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to pass `$(this)` value to a jQuery function.  The function is below but does not work.  There are no errors in console.

The function is firing because when I place an alert at the top it works.

```
(function($){
    $.fn.calculateHours = function() {
        var tbody = $(this).closest('tbody'); // get closest tbody
        var table = $(this).closest('table'); // get closest table
        var params = table.find('.disguise').serialize(); // parameters

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '/calculateHours',
            data: params,
            success: function (response) {
                // loop over object
                $.each(response.rows, function(index, array) {
                    $.each(array, function(key, value) {
                        $('#row_' + index).find('.' + key).html(value);
                    });
                });

                if($.isPlainObject(response.columns)) {
                    $.each(response.columns, function(day, hour) {
                        $('.totalsRow').find('.total_' + day).html(hour);
                    });
                }

                $('.totalsRow').find('.grand_total').html(response.grand_total);
            }
        });
    }
})(jQuery);

$(document).on('change', '.disguise', function(e) { 
    $.fn.calculateHours();
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding functions to `$.fn` is meant to extend the jQuery object. In other words, you should be calling `.calculateHours` on your jQuery object:

```
$(document).on('change', '.disguise', function(e) { 
    $(this).calculateHours();
});
```

Comment: Although my answer will work yours is actually the more correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You want jquery to set the context automatically. To do that just pass a reference to the function as the handler.

```
$(document).on('change', '.disguise', $.fn.calculateHours);
```